# Best way to get Flask variable URL input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

Consider the following Flask route:

```
@app.route("/account-details/<user_id>", methods=["GET"])
def get_account_page(user_id):
        return render_template("account-details.html")
```

The user would input the user ID manually into the URL (or be redirected to it through another page), and depending on the user ID input, the page would display information about that specific user. This information needs to be fetched from an API.

The way I've achieved this is by doing the following:

`let userID = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];`

Which gives me a variable with the user ID the user inputs in the URL. Then, when the DOM loads, I fetch the information I need to display for that user and change innerHTML of a div, to show it to them.

This works, however, there's a split second after the page loads where the information is empty, while the client is fetching the info from the API. I understand this may be impossible to avoid - but, given that I'm fairly new to web dev in general, I want to know if this is the best way to do this, or is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: You can create a loading spinner or progress bar that is displayed while the data is being fetched. Alternatively, you can create a simple "loading" message that is displayed until the data is retrieved and ready to be displayed. You can then use JavaScript to toggle the display of these elements based on the state of the data fetching process.

Comment: In addition, you can also consider implementing server-side rendering to pre-render the page with the data before sending it to the client. This can help reduce the delay and ensure that the page is fully loaded with all necessary content before it is displayed to the user. However, server-side rendering can be more complex to implement and may not always be necessary, depending on the specific requirements of your application.

Comment: @devdoesit Thank you so much! I looked into server-side rendering and this is exactly what I'm looking for here.